# Update Android UI to show random numbers being generated?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, random

I have set up a button with an onClick method called ButtonRoll which randomly generates a number from 1-100 then display the output below the button in a text view. This works fine but what I would like to move onto is to be able to cycle through 20 numbers being generated. I have tried the following the but it will only display the last number being generated. I am guessing this is because the UI isn't being updated untill the last number is generated.

```
public void ButtonRoll(View view) {

        int n;
        Random rand = new Random();
        TextView textRoll = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_roll);
        for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                n = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                String roll = String.valueOf(n);
                textRoll.setText("Random number is " + roll);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Would I have to use a Handler at all? Or is there a simpler solution?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button android:id="@+id/button_roll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Roll"/>

   <TextView android:id="@+id/textview_roll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_roll" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    private class Roller implements Runnable
    {
        private int numTimes;
        private long delayMillis;

        public Roller(int numTimes, long delayMillis)
        {
            this.numTimes = numTimes;
            this.delayMillis = delayMillis;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            if (textRoll != null)
            {
                int n = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                String roll = String.valueOf(n);
                textRoll.setText("Random number is " + roll);

                numTimes--;

                if (numTimes > 0)
                {
                    textRoll.postDelayed(this, delayMillis);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private TextView textRoll;
    private Random rand = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button_roll).setOnClickListener(this);
        textRoll = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview_roll);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        findViewById(R.id.button_roll).setOnClickListener(null);
        textRoll = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        int id = v.getId();

        if (id == R.id.button_roll)
        {
            findViewById(R.id.textview_roll).post(new Roller(20, 100));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!. Thankyou so much. I noticed the .post method which I found runs in the UI Thread. Cheers.

Comment: Right - a Runnable posted with a view gets enqueued and, when it's retrieved, it is called on the main (UI) thread.

Comment: How can I `pause` the thread and `resume` with a button click? Also, how do I `stop` the thread?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `handler` concept:

There are several ways to update your `UI` and modify a View such as a `TextView` from outside of the `UI` Thread. A `Handler` is just one method.

Here is an example that allows a single `Handler` respond to various types of requests.

```
private final static int DO_UPDATE_TEXT = 0;
private final static int DO_THAT = 1;
private final Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        final int what = msg.what;
        switch(what) {
        case DO_UPDATE_TEXT: doUpdate(); break;
        case DO_THAT: doThat(); break;
        }
    }
};
```

Update the `UI` in one of your functions, which is now on the `UI` Thread:

```
private void doUpdate() {
    myTextView.setText("updating..");
}
```

in your `asynchronous` task, send a message to the `Handler`. There are several ways to do it. This may be the simplest:

```
myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(DO_UPDATE_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 0):

After noticing the .post method as mentioned beforehand, I had a play and came up with this version which does the same. Can you see any reason why is would unadvisable to run it this way?

```
public void ButtonRoll(View view) {
        new  Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i<50;i++) {
                    try {
                         Thread.sleep(50);
                         final TextView textRoll = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_roll);
                         int n;
                         Random rand = new Random();
                         n = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
                         final String roll = String.valueOf(n);
                         textRoll.post(new Runnable() {
                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                    textRoll.setText("Random number is " + roll);
                              }
                         });
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```